# Import CSV - read file into one column - now no column delimiter

Tags: c#, ssis

I am using SQL 2008r2 SSIS. While trying to handle a log file that can have different column counts, I decided to read all the data into one column and then parse the column.

The issue I am hitting is that I am receiving an error:

> *The column delimiter for column "Column 0" was not found.*

This leads me to believe that it isn't getting to the script component to parse the column.

Does anyone have any ideas?

### File configuration

- Header row - text fields up to 50 char
- Detail row - Integers and text fields up to 50 characters

Original spec - 64 columns long

New specs     - can be 19 or 26 or 64 or unknown

Code for parsing:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    //Split Input string into string array
    string[] allValues = Row.Column1000.Split(',');

    int i = 0;

    //known Rows
    Row.Column0 = allValues[i++];
    Row.Column1 = allValues[i++];
    Row.Column2 = allValues[i++];
    Row.Column3 = allValues[i++];
    Row.Column4 = allValues[i++];
    Row.Column5 = allValues[i++];
    Row.Column6 = allValues[i++];
    Row.Column7 = allValues[i++];
    Row.Column8 = allValues[i++];
    Row.Column9 = allValues[i++];
    Row.Column10 = allValues[i++];

    //variable values - if column exists
    Row.Column11 = allValues.Length > i ? allValues[++i] : null;
    Row.Column12 = allValues.Length > i ? allValues[++i] : null;
    Row.Column13 = allValues.Length > i ? allValues[++i] : null;
    // etc
    Row.Column64 = allValues.Length > i ? allValues[++i] : null;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code you can post and an example of the log file?

Comment: Can you just cut and paste a small portion into this question?

Comment: Yes. It is configured with {CR}{LF} for header row delimiter, row delimiter and column delimiter.

Comment: Before you spend too much time on this problem, have you considered running a simple `BULK INSERT` command instead?  You can integrate it into your SSIS control flow, as a SQL Task.

Comment: I tried bulk insert and it wouldn't convert the data. I got error saying couldn't convert non-unicode to unicode. Is there a way around that?

Comment: I just tried it and my error message was: Error: 0xC002F304 at Bulk Insert Task, Bulk Insert Task: An error occurred with the following error message: "Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 65 (Column 64).".

Comment: I switched my data types in SQL to be varchar instead of nvarchar.

Comment: I am also adding 2 derived fields to the data, Can you do that after a bulk insert? That was why I was using the data conversion tool.

Comment: If the number of columns vary from one row to the next in the same log file and SSIS is expecting a consistent number of columns for the entire log file, then can you perform a search of the maximum number of columns defined (based on delimiter) in the log file and then append the appropriate number of delimiters for the other rows so that the number of columns comes out the same in the log file?

Comment: That is, if the maximum number of delimiters defined in a row is 5 and the remaining rows only show three in the same log file, can you then go to the otehr rows and add two more delimiters so that the total delimiters is 5 per row?  With that, the number of columns defined is consistent for each log file.  Or add delimiters to each row so that the columns defined in the data rows matche the number of headers.  This may require first copying the file to a temporary file and modifying that temporary file which is then imported instead of the original log file.